# change and pass variable after using onclick button (in same page)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the variable after using onclick and also want to pass new variable value to another java script as a input in same page. 
Another program is already loaded and want to reload again with new input after using onclick button.

Here what I have tried but don't know ,how to pass changed variable value in same page.

```
<div id="show_value"></div>

<input type="button" name="button1" value="Speed1" onclick="getValue('Target.B99990002')" />
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Speed1"  onclick="getValue('Target.B99990003')"/>


<script>
function getValue(speed){
document.getElementById('show_value').innerHTML = speed;

}
</script>
```

Could anybody let me know ,how to reload or pass variable value in same page after using onclick botton.

Additional information:
Please visit : 
        http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/jmol/jsmol/simple_old.htm

page. here you can see example button on right hand side.  there are four option to load different molecules like small, Fe/S, B-Dna and transcription. I also want same kind of button where on click it will change value of variable and also reload new molecule structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "Another program is already loaded and want to reload again"?

Comment: onclick variable(suppose xxxx) is used by one another programe(second program) within the same page as an input and this second program load defaut xxxx value after visiting this page.  So onclick function should perform two function "change the value of variable" and "also reload the page with changed value of xxxx". I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I don't think you understand how the web, and client side javascript works, A web page isn't a program, try re-reading your question and editing it to make more sense, also if you are using server side too (PHP, ASP) let us know.

Comment: @EaziLuizi please refer to additional information provided.

Comment: You can reload your document with either: `window.location.href = window.location.href` or `window.location.reload()` but obviously after you reload you'll start again with variable values etc unless you pass them through as GET or POST values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onClick event:

```
$('input').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).attr('value', 'yourNewValue');
    // do stuff here...
});
```

Comment: there is no JQuery tag in the question

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am done with this problem with combined approach of php and javascript.

here is solution

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['speed']))
{ ?>
<script>
var speed = "Default_value";
</script>
<? }
```

else{

```
 $jp=$_GET["speed"]; ?> 
    <script>
    var speed="<?php echo $jp;?>";
    document.getElementById('show_value').innerHTML=speed;
   </script>
   <?}?> 

 <input type="button" name="button1" value="Speed1"    onclick="getValue('Target.B99990002')" />
```

```
    <script>
     function getValue(speed1){
      location.href = window.location.pathname+'?_USE=HTML5&id=EW56D1EYUA'+'&speed='+speed1;

 }
 </script>
```

It is working fine in mine case. Thanks all.